# What does "get someone all over something" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found it in [Crash Course Media Literacy](https://youtu.be/rR7j11Wpjiw). It is at around 2 minute and 3 second. Here is the context:

> This campaign wants you to like their product because you like their spokespeople. Or a public relations firm might start a publicity campaign to **get** their client **all** **over** the media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colloquial phrase **all over** means "wherever you look, everywhere, ubiquitous".

> There was confetti **all over** the floor after the party.
>
> Did you hear about the discovery?! It's **all over** the news.

To **get** something **all over** is to cause it to be such.

> You've gotten mustard all over your shirt.
>
> We will help you get this picture of your lost dog all over town.

Comment: There are other meanings of "all over". For example, It's all over for you (meaning "the end"). Or, He's all over the map! (essentially meaning "unpredictable" or "reckless").

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it's talking about exposure. They want their client's picture and information to be broadcast by all sorts of media outlets.